# Multi party video conversation issue Skype for business online using skype web sdk

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I am working for Skype for business online using Skype web sdk.
I am trying to create multi party video conversation i.e video conference.

I am using below code to create conversation.

```
var conversation = app.conversationsManager.createConversation(); //created conversion
//self video listener
conversation.selfParticipant.video.state.changed(function (newState, reason, oldState) {
    notify("selfParticipant.video.state : "+newState)
});
//self audio listener
conversation.selfParticipant.audio.state.changed(function (newState, reason, oldState) {
    notify("selfParticipant.audio.state :"+newState);
});
//listner for conversion state
conversation.state.changed(function (newValue, reason, oldValue) {
    notify("conversation.state : "+newValue)
});

//add participants
addParticipants(conversation,sip_uris); //Added participants

notify("conversation.videoService.maxVideos : "+conversation.videoService.maxVideos());
notify("conversation.videoService.videoMode : "+conversation.videoService.videoMode());
//start video service
conversation.videoService.start().then(function () {
    notify("Video conference successfully started : "+conversation.uri());
},function (error) {
    notify("Video conference start failed : "+error);
});
```

And logs of above code as bellow

```
1:26:51 PM : selfParticipant.video.state : Disconnected
1:26:51 PM : selfParticipant.audio.state :Disconnected
1:26:51 PM : conversation.state : Created
1:26:51 PM : conversation.videoService.maxVideos : null
1:26:51 PM : conversation.videoService.videoMode : ActiveSpeaker
1:26:52 PM : conversation.state : Conferenced
1:26:53 PM : selfParticipant.audio.state :Connecting
1:26:53 PM : selfParticipant.video.state : Connecting
1:27:04 PM : selfParticipant.audio.state :Connected
1:27:04 PM : selfParticipant.video.state : Disconnected
1:27:04 PM : Video conference successfully started
```

I am having two issues.

1. [conversation.videoService.maxVideos](http://officedev.github.io/skype-docs/Skype/WebSDK/model/api/interfaces/jcafe.videoservice.html) showing as **null** on chrome()Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).
2. **selfParticipant.video.state** getting **Disconnected**, but **selfParticipant.audio.state** is fine(changing to **connected**).

**EDIT :** 
Skype web SDK logs [here](https://github.com/satishakumar/logs/blob/master/Skype%20Web%20SDK%20Video%20conference%20logs%20-%20Video%20%20Disconnect%20issue)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the logs it appears you start creating offers that include A/V (lines 266-274) and later a renegotiation has removed video from the final answer from the remote party has no lines indicate what video codecs are supported.  Are you testing Chrome to Chrome?  Have you tried testing other browsers?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I am testing chrome to chrome. Even selfparticipant video also not getting shown. I tried in firefox, I received command disabled error and again this one more issue for me.

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati .  Are you able to do skype one to one video and audio calls in Chrome 56 ?

Comment: Yes it did worked for chrome, I haven't checked for the version 56. Use conversationsManager.getConversation(sip_uri); API to connect one to one

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the 'Public Preview Key' from this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/apiproductkeys

Normally you receive the 'command disabled' error when you're using the GA-Key.

Comment: I am using correct product keys i.e. of Public Preview Key. 'command disabled' comes only on FireFox.

Comment: Actually Firefox is not even supported now: Check again the link [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/apiproductkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/apiproductkeys) and under supported browser it says: 
Firefox 40+ (non Audio/Video functionality)

We make also use of Video functionality in our product, at the moment microsoft only allows Edge (pluginless) and a few weeks ago Chrome worked also (The turned it off again)

Comment: Loaf  Thanks for information. I checked one to one working in same browser.The issue only exists for mutli party ie more than 2 users.